# VBScript Code Highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

Would it be possible to use the same Syntax Highlighter that Wikipedia uses for VBScript

If it is possible we could probably use it for all flavors of VB ([vb6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vb6),[vbscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vbscript), [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba), etc.)

Right now we have this

[image: Lame Syntax Highlighting for VBScript]

and [Wikipedia has this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)

[image: Cool Syntax Highlighting for VBScript]

---

WikiPedia uses [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi)

Answers that can only be answered by the Developers.

- Is this a different Syntax Highlighting Engine?
- Is it open source or similarly licensed?
- Could it also be used for other Coding Languages?
- Will it "Play Well" with the Stack Exchange?

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that GeSHi is written in PHP, while the current system assumes highlighting is done on the client side in JS.

Comment: @svick I hadn't looked at it that closely yet, but being PHP means that it won't play nicely with Stack Exchange because I believe that Stack Exchange is ASP.NET, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I am going to try and look into Forking the Code later and see what I can make of it, and if I can make a tester copy of a page that I can run my new version on.

Comment: @Malachi looking at the url's I'd say SE is ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I just need a sample page that I can hook the JS and CSS into I think.  but I think I am going to work on the MineSweeper thing first....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Stack Exchange syntax highlighting guide:

[**What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/241497)

> Stack Exchange does not have its own syntax highlighting engine. It
>   uses [**Google Code Prettify**](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). *Therefore, any bugs and feature requests
>   regarding syntax highlighting cannot be handled by Stack Exchange and
>   should be directed to the team behind Google Code Prettify.*

later, it says:

> If your post doesn't have the correct highlighting, it's possible it's
>   not supported. Please look at the list of supported languages. If your
>   language is not on the list, it needs to be created within the
>   Prettify project before it can be deployed by Stack Exchange. If a
>   language that could be applied to a tag is already on the list, please
>   raise a feature request here on Meta to have it deployed on the
>   network.

Comment: VBScript is supported as VB, but looks like crap.  Wiki already has nice code highlighting, my question is can we use that highlighting instead of Google Prettify?

Comment: @Malachi D'oh, meant to respond to this a while back. But what rolfl said is right. A fair amount of work has gone into making Prettify our highlighting implementation, and I don't see us trying to figure out adding SyntaxHighlight GeSHi or anything else anytime soon. Your best bet is to get VBScript supported by Prettify independently of Visual Basic.

Comment: One of these days when I have the time I will look into it again.  but thanks for the reply @Pops

Comment: @Pops I submitted a Patch Request --> https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=362&start=100  something simple though.